# Can type constructors be considered as types in functional programming languages?

Tags: scala, haskell, types, type-theory

I am approaching the Haskell programming language, and I have a background of Scala and Java developer.

I was reading the theory behind type constructors, but I cannot understand if they can be considered types. I mean, in Scala, you use the keywords `class` or `trait` to define type constructors. Think about `List[T]`, or `Option[T]`. Also in Haskell, you use the same keyword `data`, that is used for defining new types.

So, are type constructors also types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at an analogy: functions. In some branches of mathematics, functions are called *value constructors*, because that's what they do: you put one or more values in, and they construct a new value out of those.

Type constructors are exactly the same thing, except on the type level: you put one or more types in, and they construct a new type out of those. They are, in some sense, functions on the type level.

Now, to our analogy: what is the analog of the question you are asking? Well, it is this: "Can value constructors (i.e. functions) be considered as values in functional programming languages?"

And the answer is: it depends on the programming language. Now, for functional programming languages, the answer is "Yes" for almost all (if not all) of them. It depends on your definition of what a "functional programming language" is. Some people define a functional programming language as a programming language which has functions as values, so the answer will be trivially "Yes" by definition. But, some people define a functional programming language as a programming language which does not allow side-effects, and in such a language, it is not necessarily true that functions are values.

The most famous example may be John Backus' FP, from his seminal paper *Can Programming Be Liberated from the von Neumann Style? – a functional style and its algebra of programs*. In FP, there is a hierarchy of "function-like" things. Functions can only deal with values, and functions themselves are not values. However, there is a concept of "functionals" which are "function constructors", i.e. they can take functions (and also values) as input and/or produce functions as output, but they cannot take functionals as input and/or produce them as output.

So, FP is arguably a functional programming language, but it does not have functions as values.

Note: functions as values is also called "first-class functions" and functions that take functions as input or return them as output are called "higher-order functions".

If we look at some types:

```
1   :: Int
[1] :: List Int
add :: Int → Int
map :: (a → b, List a) → b
```

You can see that we can easily say: any value whose type has an arrow in it, is a function. Any value whose type has more than one arrow in it, is a higher-order function.

Again, the same applies to type constructors, since they are really the same thing except on the type level. In some languages, type constructors can be types, in some they can't. For example, in Java and C♯, type constructors are not types. You cannot have a `List<List>` in C♯, for example. You can *write down* the type `List<List>` in Java, but that is misleading, since the two `List`s mean different things: the first `List` is the type constructor, the second `List` is the *raw type*, so this is in fact *not* using a type constructor as a type.

What is the equivalent to our types example above?

```
Int     :: Type
List    :: Type ⇒ Type
→       :: (Type, Type) ⇒ Type
Functor :: (Type ⇒ Type) ⇒ Type
```

(Note, how we always have `Type`? Indeed, we are only dealing with types, so we normally don't write `Type` but instead simply write `*`, pronounced "Type"):

```
Int     :: *
List    :: * ⇒ *
→       :: (*, *) ⇒ *
Functor :: (* ⇒ *) ⇒ *
```

So, `Int` is a proper type, `List` is a type constructor that takes one type and produces a type, `→` (the function type constructor) takes two types and returns a type (assuming only unary functions, e.g. using currying or passing tuples), and `Functor` is a type constructor, which itself takes a type constructor and returns a type.

Theses "type-types" are called *kinds*. Like with functions, anything with an arrow is a type constructor, and anything with more than one arrow is a *higher-kinded type constructor*.

And like with functions, some languages allow higher-kinded type constructors and some don't. The two languages you mention in your question, Scala and Haskell *do*, but as mentioned above, Java and C♯ don't.

However, there is a complication when we look at your question:

> So, are type constructors also types?

Not really, no. At least not in any language I know about. See, while you can have higher-kinded type constructors that take type constructors as input and/or return them as output, you cannot have an expression or a value or a variable or a parameter which has a type constructor as its type. You cannot have a function that takes a `List` or returns a `List`. You cannot have a variable of type `Monad`. But, you *can* have a variable of type `Int`.

So, clearly, there is a difference between types and type constructors.

Comment: I don’t agree not being able to have a function taking a `List` and returning a `List`.  Both type synonyms and type families allow you to do exactly that.

Comment: _and Functor is a type constructor_, you said, but Functor should be a _typeclass_, and not a type constructor, shouldn't it?

Comment: Your kinds for `Functor` (and, implicitly, `Monad`) are not quite correct. Since these are type classes, they should have a kind that gives you `Constraint` (here specifically, it would be `(* -> *) -> Constraint`).

Answer (score 6):

Well, types and type constructors have a calculus of their own and they each have kinds. If you use `:k (Maybe Int)` in `ghci` for example, you'll get `*`, now this is a proper type and it (*usually*) has inhabitants. In this case `Nothing`, `Just 42`, etc. `*` now has a more descriptive alias `Type`.

Now you can look at the kind of the constructor that is `Maybe`, and `:k Maybe` will give you `* -> *`. With the alias, this is `Type -> Type` which is what you expect. It takes a `Type` and *constructs* a `Type`. Now if you see types as set of values, one good question is what set of values do `Maybe` has? Well, none because it is not really a type. You might attempt something like `Just` but that has type `a -> Maybe a` with kind `Type`, rather than `Maybe` with kind `Type -> Type`.

Comment: I'm curious why you say `Maybe a` *usually* has inhabitants. Is there a choice of `a` where `Nothing` is not an inhabitant of `Maybe a`?

Comment: I think he means a type (something of kind `*`) in general usually has values, with `Void` being an (the?) exception.

Comment: @chepner is right, that's what I meant. `Void` however is not the only exception. For example, `(Void,Void)` is a different type, but also has no inhabitants.

Answer (score 3):

At least in Haskell, there is a hierarchy that can roughly be described as follows.

*Terms* are things that exist at run-time, values like `1`, `'a'`, and `(+)`, for example.

Each term has a *type*, like `Int` or `Char` or `Int -> Int -> Int`.

Each type has a *kind*, and all types have the same kind, namely `*`.

A type constructor like `[]`, though, has kind `* -> *`, so it is not a type. Instead, it is a *mapping* from a type to a type.

---

There are other kinds as well, including (in addition to `*` and `* -> *`, with an example of each):

- `* -> * -> *` (`Either`)
- `(* -> *) -> * -> *` (`ReaderT`, a monad transformer)
- `Constraint` (`Num Int`)
- `* -> Constraint` (`Num`; this is the kind of a type class)

Comment: Functions are mappings from values to values, but they are still values. I am still not quite clear where this analogy breaks down, since type constructors and functions are more or less the same thing, but for some reason a function which maps values to values is a value itself but a type constructor which maps types to types is not a type. BTW, I think Haskell (at least with some extensions) also has *sorts*, which is the next level, i.e. the "type" of kinds.

Comment: I didn't mention sorts because 1) generally Haskell has just the one implicit sort and 2) I'm  not at all familiar with the extensions the let you define additional sorts. :) A function is really a specific kind of mapping, one from a *set* to another *set*. One way to *define* a function is to list (explicitly or implicitly) which value in the codomain of the function each value in the domain is mapped to.